# OperationContext.Current is null in .net core

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-core, operationcontext

I'm providing a WCF service in my .net core project via *SoapCore*. In one of the methods, I want to access the SOAP envelope header info. To test that, I've added the following code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService {
    [OperationContract]
    string TransmitObject(XElement node);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

public string TransmitObject(XElement node) {
    foreach(var header in OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders) {
        Console.WriteLine(header.ToString());
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(node, Formatting.None);
}
```

However, in this case, the OperationContext.Current attribute is always `null`. What do I need to change in order to make that work?

Comment: Could it be that you need to use the WebOperationContext: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: @rene According to this post, the WebOperationContext seems to be depreciated in .net core: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2686

Comment: I already was afraid of that.  bummer.